# Modify an etherpad instance with command line tool

Tags: html, curl, etherpad

Most instances of Etherpad accept setting the entire file by uploading an HTML file. Is there a way to automate this process with a command line tool such as cURL ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HTTP API](https://etherpad.org/doc/v1.8.4/#index_http_api) to create or change the content of a pad. There are several [client libraries](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/HTTP-API-client-libraries) available.

Comment: Do you any public server implementing this?

Comment: it's part of the standard install but you will need an API key. perhaps have a look at this list for a start https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/Sites-that-run-Etherpad-Lite